# How to produce ggplot's programmatically for 70+ variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I have a data frame with ~70 variables (each variable is a question), and I'd like to create plots for all of them using the same customized theme. I think this is doable with `purrr()`, but I've yet to figure out that sucker.

Essentially, I want to run each of the variables (say, i to N) through the following code:

```
  ggplot(aes(fct_rev(fct_infreq(`var_i`)))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count") +
  labs(subtitle = `var_i`) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(...) +
  ggsave("var_i.svg", device = "svg")
```

I hope to get one svg for each variable, using the variable name to populate the filename and the subtitle in the chart.

Here's an equivalent `dput()`:

```
structure(list(Species_L = c("setosa5.1", "setosa4.9", "setosa4.7", 
"setosa4.6", "setosa5", "setosa5.4", "setosa4.6", "setosa5", 
"setosa4.4", "setosa4.9", "setosa5.4", "setosa4.8", "setosa4.8", 
"setosa4.3", "setosa5.8", "setosa5.7", "setosa5.4", "setosa5.1", 
"setosa5.7", "setosa5.1"), Species_W = c("setosa3.5", "setosa3", 
"setosa3.2", "setosa3.1", "setosa3.6", "setosa3.9", "setosa3.4", 
"setosa3.4", "setosa2.9", "setosa3.1", "setosa3.7", "setosa3.4", 
"setosa3", "setosa3", "setosa4", "setosa4.4", "setosa3.9", "setosa3.5", 
"setosa3.8", "setosa3.8"), Species_PL = c("setosa1.4", "setosa1.4", 
"setosa1.3", "setosa1.5", "setosa1.4", "setosa1.7", "setosa1.4", 
"setosa1.5", "setosa1.4", "setosa1.5", "setosa1.5", "setosa1.6", 
"setosa1.4", "setosa1.1", "setosa1.2", "setosa1.5", "setosa1.3", 
"setosa1.4", "setosa1.7", "setosa1.5"), Species_PW = c("setosa0.2", 
"setosa0.2", "setosa0.2", "setosa0.2", "setosa0.2", "setosa0.4", 
"setosa0.3", "setosa0.2", "setosa0.2", "setosa0.1", "setosa0.2", 
"setosa0.2", "setosa0.1", "setosa0.1", "setosa0.2", "setosa0.4", 
"setosa0.4", "setosa0.3", "setosa0.3", "setosa0.3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: Can you include an example dataframe in reproducible form? 4 or 5 variables would be fine for this.

Comment: Will that work, @Marius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a function `my_plot_func()` then use `purrr::map()` to loop through column names

```
library(tidyverse)

my_plot_func <- function(dat, x_var) {
  p <-  ggplot(dat, aes(fct_rev(fct_infreq(.data[[x_var]])))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count") +
    labs(subtitle = x_var) +
    coord_flip()

  ggsave(paste0(x_var, "plot.svg", device = "svg")

  return(p)
}

var_names <- colnames(dat)
plot_list <- var_names %>% 
  map(~ my_plot_func(dat, .x))
plot_list
```

Comment: I don't know how to compare performance between the two answers, but from what I've read, `map` is almost always preferred over `for`. So, I'm marking this one. Thanks, Tung—this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the column names. That way, you have the column name as a string, which makes it easy to use in filenames and labels, but you have to do a bit of conversion to have it understood by `aes()`:

```
for (var_name in colnames(df)) {
    p = ggplot(df, aes(fct_rev(fct_infreq(!! sym(var_name))))) +
        geom_bar(stat = "count") +
        labs(subtitle = var_name) +
        coord_flip()
    # Need to explicitly print the plot in the loop for it to
    #   show up
    print(p)
    ggsave(paste0(var_name, ".svg"))
}
```

Comment: It'll be faster to run `ggsave(paste0(var_name, ".svg"), p)` and not `print`.

Comment: @Axeman Yep, the `print()` was just there to make sure you could actually see what was happening when the loop ran. Once you've checked it works, you can remove `print()` and just save the files.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Would a `for` loop be preferred over a vectorized approach?

Comment: I don't think there's any real way to "vectorize" this, so the `for` loop is fine. The advantages of vectorization are about the way R accesses and allocates memory, they don't apply when you're just pulling different columns out of a dataframe (and accessing the column is probably pretty minor relative to everything else that happens to produce each plot).